# Uploading image and then generating new link for it

Tags: php, html

I'm a novice to code in general but I'm trying to learn some things in my last summer before college. So far I have this much code that uploads the file to the server then displays it back within the upload.php.

How can I make it so that it generates a new link or html page with the uploaded image on it? I've looked up some possible solutions and I was thinking something along the lines of a html template that could be used for each image's individual page.

this is my upload.php I use in conjunction with an index.html form to upload the image and a description within a text file.

```
// code to save uploaded file

//finds extension to append later
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['fn']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
//creates timestamp for naming
$ran= time(). ".";


echo "<html><body>Upload Success<pre>";

/*echo var_dump($_FILES);
echo var_dump($_POST);

echo "size = ". $_FILES['fn']['size'];*/

echo "\n\n";

$picDir = "pics/" .$ran.$ext;

//saving to description text file
$dt = $_POST['ds'];
$dn= "descriptions/".$ran."txt" ;

$fh = fopen($dn, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$strData = "$dt";
fwrite($fh, $strData);
fclose($fh);
//close writing to text

//saving picture locally
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fn']['tmp_name'], $picDir);


echo "<img src=$picDir width='800'>";
echo"\n\n";
echo "$dt";

echo "</body></html>";



?>
```

Comment: You should probably wrap your `src` in quotes, ex: `<img src="$picDir" width="800"/>` ... secondly, is `pics` a path relative to _this_ php file?

Comment: echo "<img src=".$picDir." width='800'>";

Comment: what does wrapping in quotes do? When I add the quotes I get this error - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$picDir' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\upload.php on line 36

Answer (score 1):

You can use a php header to redirect the browser to a page with the new image

i.e.

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/viewImage.php?file={$picDir}/{$picName}");
```

Of course sanitize the `file` variable in this case so that people aren't able to download any file they wish from your server

Comment: ^ This. And/or only take the basename of the `$file` and use a known location along with checking for file types.